# Vue.js prevents classList.remove from working?

Tags: css, dom, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js, and I want to hide the elements until after the call to the Vue constructor because otherwise, a bunch of curly braces get flashed to the user. I have the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="main hide-me" id="my-vue-element">
    <!-- stuff -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-me {
    display: none !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var myVueElement = document.getElementById("my-vue-element");

if (myVueElement) {
    var myApp = new Vue({
        el: myVueElement
      , data: {
            /* stuff */
        }
      , methods: {
            /* stuff */
        }
    });

    console.log(myVueElement);
    console.log(myVueElement.classList);
    myVueElement.classList.remove("hide-me");
    console.log(myVueElement.classList);
    console.log(myVueElement.getAttribute("class"));
```

The console output is:

```
DOMTokenList [ "main", "hide-me" ]
DOMTokenList [ "main" ]
main
```

However, the element does not appear, and using the DOM inspectors in Firefox and in Chrome shows the `hide-me` class is still there. I've tried to reproduce this using a simplified example but am unable to do so. I do have jQuery in this same project, and I found that using `$("#my-vue-element").removeClass("hide-me");` (or even adding it after the above code) causes the class to be removed from the DOM. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use data-binding to add the class conditionally.

Comment: honestly you probably want this: [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak). "this [v-cloak] directive can be used to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready"

Comment: @birdspider, would you mind making your comment an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Direct DOM manipulation should be avoided in Vue. Instead, you should let Vue do it (it's quite good at it). So use

```
<your-element
  :class="['always-present', {'optional':expression}]"
/>
```

Where `optional` will be added/removed based on data-bound `expression`.

Additionally, you could use `v-if`, `v-show` or `v-hide` (i.e.: `v-if="expression"`), if all you want is to show/hide the element.

---

For a list of cases where direct DOM manipulation makes sense in Vue and each case's downside or potential pitfall, read [Handling Edge Cases](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize Vue views/components and their internal template code, the elements won't be rendered until Vue is ready.

Meaning inside of `app.vue` nothing shows up until the router loads the view

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```